# How to produce a local datetime string in Haskell?

Tags: datetime, haskell

I want to produce the local time and date in string form, such as, for example:

```
"2009-09-28-00-44-36.896200000000"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless I'm missing what your really after, what you want is:

```
import Data.Time

getCurrentTime
```

when run in GHCi, you get:

```
2009-09-28 01:18:27.229165 UTC
```

or, for *local* time (as you indicated and I just caught):

```
getZonedTime
```

to get:

```
2009-09-27 20:22:06.715505 CDT
```

Answer (score 6):

While *getCurrentTime* and *getZonedTime* do return the current time and local time respectively, these may not be what **liszt** is expecting. 
He wants a string that represents the present time, while both *getCurrentTime* and *getZonedTime* returns *IO UTCTime* and *IO ZonedTime* respectively

This could do what **liszt** is looking for:

```
import Data.Time
currentTime = fmap show getCurrentTime
zonedTime = fmap show getZonedTime
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

```
import System.Time

main = do ct <- getClockTime
          print ct
```

or

```
import Data.Time

main = do zt <- getZonedTime
          print zt
```

Comment: Why not `main = print =<< getClockTime`?